# Find elements from list and store nearby elements in a list - Python

Tags: python

I have a list of tokenized words and I am searching some words from it and storing nearby 3 elements to the found word. Code is :

Words_to_find -- List of words to find

tokens -- large list from which I have to find from words_to_find

```
for x in words_to_find:
        if x in tokens:
            print "Matched word is", x
            indexing = tokens.index(x)
            print "This is index :", indexing
            count = 0
            lower_limit = indexing - 3
            upper_limit = indexing + 3
            print "Limits are", lower_limit,upper_limit 
            for i in tokens:
                if count >= lower_limit and count <= upper_limit:
                    print "I have entered the if condition"
                    print "Count is : ",count
                    wording = tokens[count]
                    neighbours.append(wording)
                else:
                    count +=1
                    break
                count +=1
           final_neighbour.append(neighbours)
    print "I am in access here", final_neighbour
```

I am not able to find what is wrong in this code. I am taking lower and upper limit and trying to save that in a list and make a list of list out of it(final_neighbour).
Please help me find the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "issue", what is the issue? You didn't tell us what the issue is. What doesn't work here? What outputs are you getting?

Comment: @JennerFelton , I am getting the correct index for upper and lower limits for nearby elements, but the final_neighbour list coming out to be an empty list.

I am trying to append the nearby words for each find word in neighbours list and make a list of lists for all such words found.
Please help me with this or any better way to do this

Comment: sample IO would be helpful! `Words_to_find ` , `tokens `?

Comment: words_to_find = [u'प्रीमियम',u'एंड',u'गिव',u'फ्रॉम',u'महाराष्ट्रा',u'मुंबई',u'इंश्योरेंस',u'कंपनी',u'फॉर',u'दिस']

Comment: Please provide a sample input and the desired output for that sample input.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran ,  words_to_find = [u'प्रीमियम',u'एंड',u'गिव',u'फ्रॉम',u'महाराष्ट्रा',u'मुंबई',u'इंश्योरेंस',u'कंपनी',u'फॉर',u'दिस']

Tokens = a list of many such words

I am doing this for hindi words

Comment: Anyways, what is the output ?

Comment: Do you need the string from words_to_find along with neighbours or only the neighbours needed. ?

Comment: Based on the word found in tokens (large list of hindi words), the previous 3 and next 3 words to the word found will be the output. I will use output to show nearby elements to the word found on a web page

Comment: Am I clear on the expected output ?

Comment: @Suresh, I need the string from of neighbours

Comment: Shouldn't ``tokens.index(x)`` be ``words_to_find.index(x)``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use slicing to get the neighbours rather than iterating using counts.

```
tokens = [u'प्रीमियम',u'एंड',u'गिव',u'फ्रॉम',u'महाराष्ट्रा',u'मुंबई',u'इंश्योरेंस',u'कंपन‌​ी',u'फॉर',u'दिस']
words_to_find = [u'फ्रॉम',u'महाराष्ट्रा']
final_neighbours = {}
for i in words_to_find:
    if i in tokens:
       print "Matched word : ",i
       idx = tokens.index(i)
       print "this is index : ",idx
       idx_lb = idx-3
       idx_ub = idx+4
       print "Limits : ",idx_lb,idx_ub
       only_neighbours =  tokens[idx_lb : idx_ub]
       only_neighbours.remove(i)
       final_neighbours[i]= only_neighbours

for k,v in final_neighbours.items():
    print "\nKey:",k
    print "Values:"
    for i in v:
       print  i,

 Output:
  Matched word :  फ्रॉम
  this is index :  3
  Limits :  0 7
  Matched word :  महाराष्ट्रा
  this is index :  4
  Limits :  1 8

  Key: महाराष्ट्रा
  Values:
  एंड गिव फ्रॉम मुंबई इंश्योरेंस कंपन‌​ी 
  Key: फ्रॉम
  Values:
  प्रीमियम एंड गिव महाराष्ट्रा मुंबई इंश्योरेंस
```

Comment: This method works fine.. Thanks..
My only concern that I have words in hindi and I have to convert them in  unicode to use it .. Now my output looks like this

'  {u'\u092e\u0941\u0902\u092c\u0908': [u'\u0930\u091c\u093f\u0938\u094d\u091f\u0930\u094d\u0921', u'\u092b\u094d\u0930\u0949\u092e', u'\u092e\u0939\u093e\u0930\u093e\u0937\u094d\u091f\u094d\u0930\u093e', u'\u092e\u0941\u0902\u092c\u0908', u'\u0930\u093e\u0907\u091f', u'\u0938\u0930', u'\u092f\u094b\u0930'] '

Is there any way to see the hindi words

Comment: If you print the words separately, you will be able to see hindi words. Have edited my code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you also explain logic behind that. Does it convert the unicode to ASCII when printed separately. But hindi letters are not supported in ASCII

Comment: Unicode is superset of ASCII. To learn about unicode, check this, 
http://www.diveintopython.net/xml_processing/unicode.html
and Hindi characters belongs to Devanagiri unicode block,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_(Unicode_block)

Answer (score 0):

The neighbour for each word changes. Therefore make it null every word. And also count should be assigned to indexing-3, that is lower_limit if its >=0 otherwise 0, as the previous and next three words from the word found is what you need.

```
for x in words_to_find:
    neighbours=[] # the neighbour for the new word will change, therefore make it null!
    if x in tokens:
        print "Matched word is", x
        indexing = tokens.index(x)
        print "This is index :", indexing
        lower_limit = indexing - 3
        upper_limit = indexing + 3
        count = lower_limit if lower_limit >=0 else 0# lower_limit starts from the index-3 of the word found!
        print "Limits are", lower_limit,upper_limit,count
        for i in tokens:
            if count >= lower_limit and count <= upper_limit:
                print "I have entered the if condition"
                print "Count is : ",count
                wording = tokens[count]
                neighbours.append(wording)
            else:
                count +=1
                break
            count +=1
        final_neighbour.append(neighbours)
    print "I am in access here", final_neighbour
```

Sample IO(some random token and words_to_find for testing purpose):

```
tokens='hi this is hi keerthana hello world hey hi hello'.split()
words_to_find=['hi','hello']
I am in access here [['hi', 'this', 'is', 'hi'], ['is', 'hi', 'keerthana', 'hello', 'world', 'hey', 'hi']]
```

**Suggestion**

You can use list slicing to get the 3 words before and after the matched word. This will also give the desired output!

```
lower_limit = lower_limit if lower_limit >=0 else 0
neighbours.append(tokens[lower_limit:upper_limit+1])
```

That is,

```
final_neighbour=[]
for x in words_to_find:
    neighbours=[] # the neighbour for the new word will change, therefore make it null!
    if x in tokens:
        print "Matched word is", x
        indexing = tokens.index(x)
        print "This is index :", indexing
        lower_limit = indexing - 3
        upper_limit = indexing + 3
        lower_limit = lower_limit if lower_limit >=0 else 0# lower_limit starts from the index-3 of the word found!
        print "Limits are", lower_limit,upper_limit
        neighbours.append(tokens[lower_limit:upper_limit+1])
        final_neighbour.append(neighbours)
    print "I am in access here", final_neighbour
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: List comprehension will convert it into list of list of list : 

[[[u'\u091f\u0942', u'\u0930\u093f\u0915\u0949\u0930\u094d\u0921', u'\u092f\u094b\u0930', u'\u092a\u094d\u0930\u0940\u092e\u093f\u092f\u092e', u'\u090f\u0902\u0921', u'\u0917\u093f\u0935', u'\u092f\u0942']]]

Comment: Also because I am dealing with hindi words it stores in unocode.. Any direct method to view the exact hindi words directly. When I access the element one by one it prints in hindi, but looking for a better way

Answer (score -1):

You have line below in for loop

```
neighbours.append(wording)
```

What is  "neighbours" ??

you should initialize it(Especially outside of loop... prefer to use at start of code where you defined tokens and Words_to_find) as below before the append statement

```
neighbours[]
```